# Error when using ModalRoute to retrieve arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting null every time I call modalroute to retrieve arguments from a named route.

This is the code snippet:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
           context, 
           VerifyCode.routeName, 
           arguments: {'code': randValue,},
           );
```

This is where I retrieve the argument:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
{
   //Get the dialog provider to display information
   alertViewModel = Provider.of<AlertViewModel>(context);

   //Retrieve the route argument
   final routeArgs =
           ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, int>;

    final securityCode = routeArgs['code']; <-- Error happens here

    print('Code =' + securityCode.toString());
   return Container()
```

}

I should be getting a integer from the map but instead I am getting the error:

```
 ════════ Exception Caught By widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building VerifyCode(dirty, dependencies: [InheritedProvider<AlertViewModel>, _ModalScopeStatus], state: _VerifyCodeState#98992):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("code")
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
#1      _VerifyCodeState.build package:accidentapp/screens/verifycode.dart:42
#2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4012
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3924
#4      Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3721 ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The routeArgs is always null.  I have tried using a class to pass the value instead of the map but I am getting the same error.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Pass settings to MaterialPageRoute

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
return MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    //some custom code
    return Page();
  },
  settings: settings
);
```

}

Comment: I did the same but can not get argument:
type 'RouteSettings' is not a subtype of type 'AuthenticationArguments' in type cast

Comment: put this code in your widget`final argument = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as AuthenticationArguments;`

Comment: I already found the root cause. I've passed the source argument into a RouteSettings then passing RouteSettings into push/pushName method of Navigator. Anyway, thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way :-**

```
 String rawJson = '{"code":randValue}';
 Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);

 Navigator.pushNamed(context, VerifyCode.routeName, arguments: map);
```

**recieve data using :-**

```
final Map<String, dynamic> map = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

**You can get data using**

```
map["code"]
```

Comment: Hey I've tested my code its working . Can you post whole your code ? Then may be I'll be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I solve it but I am still not sure what I have did not work.  I was using onGenerateroute on MaterialApp.  I put all my named routes in a router.dart file.  However, when I moved the name routes to the routes: table on Material App it works fine.  Why is this so?

Comment: @WXM1967 Both way are fine and working you can check the demo on flutter's website here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments my guess is that you may be missing something on your code .    Cheers for you your code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Map place holders

```
final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
```